# Are there Chat Apps APIs that allow users to send freely any message to any contact

Tags: api, chat, whatsapp

I had the project to build a minimalist phone, with a micro controller and and a sim module.

The main feature would have been to be able to communicate with **whatsapp**. But after playing around with **Twilio** and other similar providers, I realized that the **Whatsapp Business API** (as it may suggest) is not for that purpose, to send freely any messages to your friends, but was more about sending template messages, that have to be accepted first by whatsapp.

But also for the other chat apps, (like Telegram), I always came across "**bot APIs**" that just allow you to communicate with your own number, but nothing more. So, isn't there any chat app that would allow users to communicate through an API, the same way we do on their native App?

Comment: I don't think any of the messengers have a real API. For Signal there exist a command-line version that mimics a client. Some messengers have web based versions, but usually they require to be connected to a real phone which holds the actual account.

Answer (score 0):

The [Matrix protocol](https://matrix.org/) is an open protocol for messaging (although it can also support other use cases).  There are various clients for it that you can find on the website.  The protocol works by just sending JSON content to various API endpoints, so you can even send messages using a barebones method like curl.  There are bot libraries for it as well (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/i10b/simplematrixbotlib)).